# ASP:Menu : Need to apply CSS to make bulleted lists

Tags: asp.net, css, aspmenu, aspmenu-control, bulletedlist

I am using ASP:Menu and I would like to have the menu shown as below. Please suggest how to apply the CSS and what changes should I make?

Products

- Instock
- Out-of-Stock

Orders

- Purchase Orders
- Sales Orders

  - Back Orders
  - Invoices

ASP:Menu code is as below.

```
<asp:Menu runat="server" ID="Navigator" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" StaticDisplayLevels="3" 
Orientation="Vertical" DataSourceID="RelativeSiteMapDataSource"   />
```

Update1: The current html that is generated by ASP:menu is shown below.

```
<ul class="Menu"> 
<li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="prodxeon/products.aspx"; class="Menu-Link" title="Products">Products</a></li>
<li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="prodxeon/orders.aspx"; class="Menu-Link" title="Orders">Orders</a></li> 
    <ul>
        <li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://pdxeon/po.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Purchase Orders">Purchase Orders</a></li>
        <li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://pdxeon/so.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Sales Orders">Sales Orders</a></li>
            <ul>    
                <li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://pdxeon/Bso.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Back Orders">Back Orders</a></li>               
                <li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://pdxeon/iso.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Invoices">Invoices</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You don't know how to write the css, or you dont know how to apply css to asp tags?

Comment: This is a client-side issue. Please show your HTML, not your server-side ASP code.

Comment: @Forty-Two: asp:menu has few tags for CSS but in my case I want only the submenu and sub-submenu items to be idented and bulleted. I am not aware of this and hence looking for direction. Sorry if it is a simple question.

Comment: @Diodeus: asp:menu renders the output through html. so I am not puttin the html stuff on the page. I am not able to understand your reply.

Comment: CSS styles HTML, it does not style .NET. Therefore, the actual HTML being generated is important for others to be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Diodeus: I have added the HTML that is currently generated as UPDATE1 in my original post. Please refer the same and let me know what changes I need to make to asp:Menu. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
ul.Menu {  margin:0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em; }
ul.Menu li {     list-style-type:disc; }
ul.Menu ul {     margin:0 3em 1.5em 1.5em; }
```

Keep in mind that your HTML is broken.

```
<li class="Menu-Leaf"><a href="http://pdxeon/so.aspx" class="Menu-Link" title="Sales Orders">Sales Orders</a></li>
     <ul>   <--- this should be before the </li>. Lists must be nested. Any tag outside </li> is illegal.
```

Nested lists must follow this pattern:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <ul>
           <li>...</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is one of the problems with .NET controls - they isolate you from the HTML far too much, providing the developer with convenient ways to do things quickly, without understanding the fundamentals of how HTML actually works.

Comment: :thanks for the inputs and html suggestion. I added the above CSS as MenuTest in my stylesheet and tried to reference within CSSClass in asp:menu but it doesn't work. Also my stylesheet gave errors for using "ul". Any suggestions?

Comment: This is what I get in the stylesheet when I hover over "ul" as it underlines it with red color. Validation (CSS 2.1): 'ul' is not a known CSS property name.

Comment: There must be some existing CSS that's doing this.

Comment: Thanks.It doesn't allow me to up-vote yet. I will check the stylesheet and get back to you on this.      Meanwhile can anyone help me as to which tag in asp:menu I should use to get the display style I am looking for?

Comment: It is not working. I copied in stylesheet but no success. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @diedeus: I have marked it as answered as stylesheet works but I am unable to get the whole issue resolved...